# Blu-ray drives vs burners

Tags: blu-ray

Would there be any inherent benefit of using a burner for reading a Blu-ray disk vs just a regular drive? Like more memory, more power, etc.. It seems logical that a device that also had the capability to burn might perform better when reading.

Comment: There's more ti truth than logic.

Comment: @Xavierjazz lol -.- Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 3):

Having the capabilities of burning a disc provides no benefit to reading a disc.

Comment: Could you provide some evidence? Is this from personal experience doing benchmarks? Are you a hardware professional? Did you read this somewhere? Thank you! :)

Comment: I must disagree.  In my experience burners fare better at reading marginal disks.